# Using if and else statements to write an "addition" program

Tags: c, if-statement

im new to C and trying to write a program where it shows numOne + numTwo = total using just if, else if and else statements.

Any numbers that are between zero and ten should show as words (negative numbers between negative ten and zero also appear as words)  All other numbers appear as decimal integers.

e.g. integers 10 and 5 should read:
ten + five = 15

Repeating my code for numOne would give me almost 300 lines, surely there is a more efficient method of utilising these if and else statements? ty

the code i have so far is :

```
// edited code 

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)  {
    int numOne;
    int numTwo; 
    printf("Please enter two integers:");
    scanf("%d %d", &numOne, &numTwo); 


    if (numOne >= -10 && numOne < 0) {
       printf("negative");    
    }
    if (numOne == 0) {
        printf("zero + ");
    }
    if (numOne == 1) {
        printf("one + ");
    }
    if (numOne == 2) {
        printf("two + ");
    }
    if (numOne == 3) {
        printf("three + ");
    }
    if (numOne == 4) {
        printf("four + ");
    }
    if (numOne == 5) {
        printf("five + ");
    }
    if (numOne == 6) {
        printf("six + ");
    }
    if (numOne == 7) {
        printf("seven + ");
    }
    if (numOne == 8) {
        printf("eight + ");
    }
    if (numOne == 9) {
        printf("nine + ");
    }
    if (numOne == 10) {
        printf("ten + ");
    }

    if (numTwo >= -10 && numTwo < 0){
       printf("negative");    
    }
    if (numTwo == 0) {
        printf("zero");
    }
    if (numTwo == 1) {
        printf("one");
    }
    if (numTwo == 2) {
        printf("two");
    }
    if (numTwo == 3) {
        printf("three");
    }
    if (numTwo == 4) {
        printf("four");
    }
    if (numTwo == 5) {
        printf("five");
    }
    if (numTwo == 6) {
        printf("six");
    }
    if (numTwo == 7) {
        printf("seven");
    }
    if (numTwo == 8) {
        printf("eight");
    }
    if (numTwo == 9) {
        printf("nine");
    }
    if (numTwo == 10) {
        printf("ten");
    }
    int total = numOne + numTwo;
    if (total >= -10 && total < 0) {
       printf("negative");    
    }
    if (total == 0) {
        printf("zero");
    }
    if (total == 1) {
        printf("one");
    }
    if (total == 2) {
        printf("two");
    }
    if (total == 3) {
        printf("three");
    }
    if (total == 4) {
        printf("four");
    }
    if (total == 5) {
        printf("five");
    }
    if (total == 6) {
        printf("six");
    }
    if (total == 7) {
        printf("seven");
    }
    if (total == 8) {
        printf("eight");
    }
    if (total == 9) {
        printf("nine");
    }
    if (total == 10) {
        printf("ten");
    }


    else if (numOne > 10 || numOne < -10) {
            printf("%d + ", numOne);
    } else if (numTwo > 10 || numTwo < -10) {
            printf("%d = ", numTwo);
    } else if (total > 10 || total < -10) {
            printf("%d", total);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

old:

````
int main(void)  {
    int numOne;
    int numTwo;
    int total = numOne + numTwo; 
    printf("Please enter two integers:");
    scanf("%d %d", numOne, numTwo); 



 // repeat all this code for numTwo and total    
    if (numOne = -1) {
        printf("negative one + ");
    }
    if (numOne = -2); {
        printf("negative two + ");
    }
    if (numOne = -3) {
        printf("negative three + ");
    }
    if (numOne = -4); {
        printf("negative four + ");
    }
    if (numOne = -5) {
        printf("negative five + ");
    }
    if (numOne = -6); {
        printf("negative six + ");
    }
    if (numOne = -7) {
        printf("negative seven + ");
    }
    if (numOne = -8); {
        printf("negative eight + ");
    }
    if (numOne = -9) {
        printf("negative nine + ");
    }
    if (numOne = -10); {
        printf("negative ten + ");
    }

    if (numOne = 0) {
        printf("zero + ");
    }
    if (numOne = 1) {
        printf("one + ");
    }
    if (numOne = 2); {
        printf("two + ");
    }
    if (numOne = 3) {
        printf("three + ");
    }
    if (numOne = 4); {
        printf("four + ");
    }
    if (numOne = 5) {
        printf("five + ");
    }
    if (numOne = 6); {
        printf("six + ");
    }
    if (numOne = 7) {
        printf("seven + ");
    }
    if (numOne = 8); {
        printf("eight + ");
    }
    if (numOne = 9) {
        printf("nine + ");
    }
    if (numOne = 10); {
        printf("ten + ");
    }





    else if (numOne > 10 || < -10) {
            printf("%d + ", numOne);
    } else if (numTwo > 10 || < -10) {
            printf("%d = ", numTwo);
    } else if (total > 10 || < -10) {
            printf("%d", total);
    }


    return 0; 
} ```
````

Comment: You could create a function `showNum(int num)` that shows a number. Then you could test that function to make sure it works. Hint: the code you have isn't close to working, even for the first number.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the *first* thing I would do would be to put a function in to do this, since you may want to call it from multiple places.

Beyond that, you can simply realise that there are some very common cases and ways to drive your decisions with data rather than code:

1. All negative numbers can be represented by the word "negative" followed by the text of the absolute value (`7 -> "seven", -7 -> "negative seven"`).
2. For positive numbers greater than 99, they're simply `X` hundred and something.
3. For positive numbers in the range `20..99`, they are simply the tens prefix followed by the units digit ("twenty-seven", sixty-seven, etc).
4. You can look up textual representations of digits with very simple formulae.

To that end, here's a complete program showing these things in action, for numbers in the range `-999..999`, with a test harness for validation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// printNum:
// Prints a number in the range -999..999 inclusive, as text.
// Params:
//    prefixFmt: A printf-style format with at most one "%d",
//               for printing number first. NULL means no
//               output. Useful for debugging.
//    num:       The actual number to print. If outside
//               allowed range, prints "<UNKNOWN>".
//    suffix:    String to print after number (eg, "", "\n").

void printNum(char *prefixFmt, int num, char *suffix) {
    // Lookup tables to make code smaller.

    static const char *specials[] = {
        "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen",
        "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };
    static const char *tens[] = {
        "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy",
        "eighty", "ninety" };
    static const char *ones[] = {
        "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven",
        "eight", "nine" };

    // Output prefix if requested.

    if (prefixFmt != NULL)
        printf(prefixFmt, num);

    // Protect from out-of-range.

    if (num < -999 || num > 999) {
        printf("<UNKNOWN>%s", suffix);
        return;
    }

    // Handle negatives and zero as special cases. After
    // this block, number is guaranteed 1..999. Suborn the
    // first argument to printNum to output "negative",
    // original has already been used above.

    if (num <= 0) {
        if (num == 0)
            printf("zero%s", suffix);
        else
            printNum("negative ", -num, suffix);
        return;
    }

    // Handle hundreds prefix if needed and adjust to 1..99.

    if (num > 99) {
        printf("%s hundred", ones[num / 100 - 1]);
        if (num % 100 != 0)
            printf(" and ");
        num = num % 100;
    }

    // Handle 10..19 within each hundred block as special case.

    if (num >= 10 && num <= 19) {
        printf("%s%s", specials[num - 10], suffix);
        return;
    }

    // Handle tens prefix if needed, adjust to 1..9.

    if (num > 19) {
        printf("%s", tens[num / 10 - 2]);
        if (num % 10 != 0)
            putchar(' ');
        num = num % 10;
    }

    // Finally, output units digit and suffix.

    if (num != 0)
        printf("%s", ones[num - 1]);
    printf("%s", suffix);
}

// Test harness.

int main() {
    // First, convert every possibility for eyeball check.

    for (int i = -999; i <= 999; ++i)
        printNum("%5d: ", i, "\n");
    puts("=====");

    // Then do sample adds around zero.

    for (int i = -2; i <= 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = -2; j <= 3; ++j) {
            printNum(NULL, i, " PLUS ");
            printNum(NULL, j, " EQUALS ");
            printNum(NULL, i + j, "\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The final bit of that test harness output shows that the additions work:

```
negative two PLUS negative two EQUALS negative four
negative two PLUS negative one EQUALS negative three
negative two PLUS zero EQUALS negative two
negative two PLUS one EQUALS negative one
negative two PLUS two EQUALS zero
negative two PLUS three EQUALS one
negative one PLUS negative two EQUALS negative three
negative one PLUS negative one EQUALS negative two
negative one PLUS zero EQUALS negative one
negative one PLUS one EQUALS zero
negative one PLUS two EQUALS one
negative one PLUS three EQUALS two
zero PLUS negative two EQUALS negative two
zero PLUS negative one EQUALS negative one
zero PLUS zero EQUALS zero
zero PLUS one EQUALS one
zero PLUS two EQUALS two
zero PLUS three EQUALS three
one PLUS negative two EQUALS negative one
one PLUS negative one EQUALS zero
one PLUS zero EQUALS one
one PLUS one EQUALS two
one PLUS two EQUALS three
one PLUS three EQUALS four
two PLUS negative two EQUALS zero
two PLUS negative one EQUALS one
two PLUS zero EQUALS two
two PLUS one EQUALS three
two PLUS two EQUALS four
two PLUS three EQUALS five
three PLUS negative two EQUALS one
three PLUS negative one EQUALS two
three PLUS zero EQUALS three
three PLUS one EQUALS four
three PLUS two EQUALS five
three PLUS three EQUALS six
```

---

In terms of the requirement of only doing numbers in the range `-10..10` as textual, that can be done with a separate function, something like (no debug prefix for this one, but preserving the suffix since it's useful for adding spacing or newlines):

```
void printNumTestOrNum(int val, char *suffix) {
    if (val < -10 or val > 10)
        printf("%d%s", val, suffix);
    else
        printNum(NULL, val, suffix);
}
```

Comment: "All negative numbers are simply the word "negative" followed by the equivalent positive number."  That would be absolute value.  A negative number cannot be positive, but it does have an absolute value.

Comment: @jwdonahue, you're correct but it's also correct to say that the equivalent positive number for -42 is 42. At no point did I say that a negative number would be positive. However, will change the text to ensure no misunderstanding.

Comment: Sorry, I tend to be a bit pedantic late in the evenings, after a few beers, but "equivalent" has an exact meaning in mathematics that implies -42 != 42 under any circumstances.  However, in laymen's terms, you were correct enough.  Apologies.

Comment: @jwdonahue: depends on how you define the "valent" part of equi-valent, whether the value includes the sign or not :-) And don't ever apologise for being pedantic, it's also a bug-bear of mine much of the time - though I tend to get *less* so with alcohol intake.

Comment: "depends on how you define the 'valent' part...", ROFL.